# Google Chrome: click button in the tool bar using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, applescript

I am writing an Applescript that controls Chrome. Now I need to click a button in the toolbar (I think that is what it is called - I am referring to this UI element:

[image: toolbar]
)

Can this be done using Javascript or something like that (Maybe there are some internal Chrome functions or similar?)?

Answer (score -1):

have you looked at the [browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) ? I think there is somenthing there should help you to achieve that